# Two poisson processes - no independence

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Say I have two poisson processes which are not independent,

$N_t$: The number of cars that go over a bridge, with rate 10 per minute

There is a 7/10 chance that cars going over this bridge are red. Therefore,

$M_t$: The number of red cars that go over a bridge, with rate 7 per minute

How would I calculate probabilities between these dependent events, $P(N_1=5,M_{0.5}=4)$? (i.e. probability of 4 red cars in 0.5 minutes and 5 total cars in a minute)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, we want the probability of $4$ red cars in the first half-minute, and a total of $5$ cars in the first minute. Given that there are $4$ reds in the first half-minute, this event can happen in $2$ ways: (i) $0$ non-reds in the first half-minute, and $1$ car (any colour) in the next half minute or (ii) $1$ non-red in the first half minute, and $0$ cars in the next half-minute.

We calculate the probability of (i) and leave the computation of (ii), and the addition, to you.

The number of non-reds in a half-minute has Poisson distribution, parameter $3/2$. So the probability of $0$ non-reds in the first half-minute is $e^{-3/2}$. The probability of $1$ car in the next half minute is $e^{-5}\frac{5^1}{1!}$. Because of independence, we multiply.

**Added:** Putting things together, we get that the probability of $4$ reds in the first half-minute, and a total of $5$ cars in the first minute, is
$$e^{-7/2}\frac{(7/2)^4}{4!}\left[e^{-3/2}\frac{(3/2)^0}{0!}e^{-5}\frac{5^1}{1!}+ e^{-3/2}\frac{(3/2)^1}{1!}e^{-5}\frac{5^0}{0!}                        \right].$$

Comment: Why do you calculate 0 non-reds instead of 4 reds in the first 0.5 minutes?

Comment: The whole sum (i) plus (ii) will have to be multiplied by the probabilty of $4$ reds, which I am sure you can handle, but for the record it is $e^{-7/2}\frac{(7/2)^4}{4!}$.

Comment: So is it correct to say $$P(N_1=5,M_{0.5}=4) $$ $$ = P(N_{0.5}=4,N_{1}-N_{0.5}=1,M_{0.5}=4) + P(N_{0.5}=4,N_{1}-N_{0.5}=1,M_{0.5}=4)$$ $$ = P(N_{0.5}=4,N_{1}-N_{0.5}=1,N_{0.5}-M_{0.5}=0) + P(N_{0.5}=4,N_{1}-N_{0.5}=1,N_{0.5}-M_{0.5}=1)$$, and then you can split each probability into 3 due to independence?

Comment: It looks incorrect to me. The notation does not help. It definitely does not involve $N_{0.5}=4$. Maybe I will add something to the answer.

Comment: I have written an explicit expression. Note that the "multiplier" is, in your notation, $\Pr(M_{0.5}=4)$. Or, in my "notation", the probability of $4$ red cars in the first half-minute.

Comment: I made a mistake in my last comment, sorry.

Comment: What is I meant was...
$$P(N_1=5,M_{0.5}=4)$$
$$=P(N_{0.5}=4,N_1−N_{0.5}=1,M_{0.5}=4)+P(N_{0.5}=5,N_1−N_{0.5}=0,M_{0.5}=4)$$
$$=P(N_{0.5}−M_{0.5}=0,N_1−N_{0.5}=1,M_{0.5}=4)+P(N_{0.5}−M_{0.5}=1,N_1−N_{0.5}=0,M_{0.5}=4)$$
Due to independence:
$$=P(N_{0.5}−M_{0.5}=0)P(N_1−N_{0.5}=1)P(M_{0.5}=4)+P(N_{0.5}−M_{0.5}=1)P(N_1−N_{0.5}=0)P(M_{0.5}=4)$$
This gives the same answer as your answer but would like to know if the intermediate steps are correct. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the first few lines say in symbols what I was saying in words, and the last calculational line is in principle what I used.  The point is that non-independence is awkward, so one does cases in order to recover independence.